PHP Switch Case reference in html using include
I am referencing switch thats in the include file on an html page:
bpost.php
<?php
    switch ($bpost) {
        case "2":
            $VAR2 = "Template 1"; 
            $BLOG_TITLE = "Template 2;
            break;
            
        case "1":
            $VAR2 = "Template"; 
            $BLOG_TITLE = "Template ";
            break;
            
        default:
            $VAR2 = "Blog"; 
            $BLOG_TITLE = " Blog";
    }

?>

in my html file i have include("include/bloginfo.php");
When I want to use the case variables to fill in data, I have to reference the include everytime like this.
<li>
    <?php $bpost = "1"; include("include/bloginfo.php");?>
                                                
    <div class="post-info">
        <a href="<?php print $LINK; ?>"><?php print $BLOG_TITLE; ?></a>
        <div class="post-meta">
             <?php print $VAR2; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <?php $bpost = "2"; include("include/bloginfo.php"); ?>

    <div class="post-info">
        <a href="<?php print $LINK; ?>"><?php print $BLOG_TITLE; ?></a>
        <div class="post-meta">
            <?php print $VAR2;  ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

Is there a better way to do this so I only include the bloginfo.php file at the begining of the page, and I can <<?php $bpost = "2"; > around the divs I would want the data to populate inside of?
Right now, I am just referencing the include around the divs I need the data to populate, which seems like I am loading the data redundantly.

Hint: do you know what a function is?

New to PHP, any help would be apprecaited

Well that was my suggestion - put the code from bloginfo.php in a function which accepts the relevant input, and returns the relevant value(s) back again. Then you only need to declare and include it once, and you can call it as many times as you like. I'll assume if you've got as far as using things like switch and include that you've covered functions already in your learning materials?

I just don't know how to set it up to use it where I can reference data from a specific group to print inside the html page

Not really sure what you mean? A function can accept an input value, or values. You're probably going to want to pass $bpost into it, I'd expect. The function can then use those input values within the function, to help control what happens, and what it returns. Does that help? I'm trying to get you to figure this out yourself instead of spoon-feeding a ready-made answer, because you should be capable of at least attempting it, and the learning process is important.

Hint 2: Since your switch statement current sets 2 variables, you might want to consider making the function return an (associative) array which contains both of those values, and then the calling code can use the relevant return value later on (e.g. to echo it)

P.S. Why is a switch statement driving this anyway? If this is a list of blog posts, shouldn't that be stored in a data structure (e.g. database table, JSON file, or even an array in PHP) which you then simply loop through to output all the available posts? Otherwise, when you add a new post, you have to change your code and add a new clause to the switch, and duplicate a whole load of HTML, which seems pretty inefficient.

I am just using this for a personal website for my business and only have limited php/html experience. Just finding a simple way to add a blog section that I can periodically update. All that you mentioned is way about my knowledge grade; I am just piecing together what I found online on how to possibly make it work and get the switch stuff from there. If there is a better way, I would appreciate it. But I don't know how to do it myself. I am just trying to create something for a non tech related business so I have a decent web presence

Ah. Ok. If you want a "decent" web presence, don't DIY, especially if you have almost no idea what you're doing. There are tools out there you can build a website with drag and drop and pretty much no code, or you can buy cheap templates for very little, or have someone build you a small site fairly cheaply, but one which actually can take advantage of SEO, meets modern web standards, is secure, and that you can maintain and add content to without having to manually update HTML and PHP pages yourself - that's what we did 20 years ago and it wasn't much fun. The world has moved on, considerably

Do you even need a traditional website as such? Many small businesses just have socials. It's often easier to make your presence felt, and you can run the whole thing from your phone.

If you really want to do it your way, then use this to get you started: https://3v4l.org/VttpO . But have a serious think about your overall approach to this project.

I do have a template, but it's just HTML. I found blog tools where you use JS script, but I noticed that if I share the blog posts on social media with JS blogs, the image title tags do not populate correctly. I have plenty of HTML experience and do not mind doing the work; I just need help with this PHP bit, and I was hoping someone who knows a better way can show me. Everything else is working great, just wanted to see if I can do this part so I dont have to update things individually.

Again, if you could demonstrate an example function code, that would be great; if not, that is good too. I just don't want to go back and forth on things off-topic on what I should be doing. Like I said, it's about 95% done, I just want to see if I can add this.

I just did, see my last comment

Or even better, without the cumbersome switch statement or manual repetition of calls to the function with hard-coded numbers, let's make it properly data-driven: https://3v4l.org/2l7Ac . Later you can think about switching out the static array for some info you load from a database table (which then enables you to have another page in your site for entering and maintaining that data without needing to edit code by hand, if you want to).

Sweet, I will check it out. I saw a PHP script that I could install that uses MySQL and everything to do it programmatically. I just don't need that much for this project, Just want to get something simple that I can run for now. If I need to do something where I am posting bi-weekly or even monthly then I'd def look into that

Ok. The advantage of the code in my last demo is that to add a new entry you only need to add one line of code/data, into the $blogData array, rather than adding a whole new case to the switch, and replicating a whole lot of other code to produce a new entry in the page.

Thanks the second worked great! quick question -- for the post page, how would I print data just for a specific group, like like blog Template 2 just only need to print the var2 and link for that on a page? thanks again I appreciate it!

Are you saying you only want to print a specific record from the array, on that page? In that case, you'd need to just take that one item from the array, e.g. $blogData[1] or whatever

Are we ignoring the missing double quote in the include file?

@mickmackusa Yep. Clearly a typo when adding the question. Not sure why people don't copy and paste. But it's obviously not the issue, otherwise the question would be about a syntax error

I appreciate the help on this, I got it working I think I have what I need
